# Is it possible to detect linear motion of a billiard cue using a crude potentiometer?

Tags: arduino, sensor, potentiometer, motion

I’m working on a project that simulates the motion of a billiard cue. I’m thinking of using an Arduino Uno for communication and an MPU6050 module for detecting angular rotation.

For detecting linear motion however, I’m thinking of using some form of conductor (like a single copper wire or aluminum foil strip) along the cue length connected to a wire. This would rub against a small conductor at the bridge of the hand. The cue wire would be connected to 5 V power and the conductor at the bridge would be connected to Arduino’s analog input pin.

The Uno has a sample rate of 15 ksamples/s and a voltage sensitivity of 1 mV. Will this setup work? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about the accelerometer built into the mpu6050? That detects linear acceleration quite well

Comment: @Bryan I want to detect even slow motion, like when the player feathers (back and forth motion) before shot. I don’t think that would be possible to detect with the accelerometer.

Comment: I’d try it out and see, since it’s already part of your BOM, and if it’s unsatisfactory then use absolute positioning solutions like the proposed linear resistor.

Comment: Any moving contact point between electrical contacts will give you an unpredictable resistance possibly even a few brief open connections. Why not use a large grid pattern in inches (or cm) on the table then take a digital video of the cue action.  Then play the video back using almost any digital video player software with a time display. The speed of motion can be calculated by comparing the cue locations on the grid and the video time difference between the location points. Also (as in the comment) accelerometer data from the MPU6050 with a fixed time frame would also give you displacement.

Comment: The way accelerometers workin internally, I think they are only good for quick jerky motion detection. Will still try it out though. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Nedd, I’m trying to simulate the entire motion of the cue as the player feathers, pauses at the end and goes through.I need the data in real time and i’m low on budget. The video recording option would be great but requires expensive setup to get realtime data.

Comment: use an optical mouse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you approach a problem, it's important not to jump to design conclusions prematurely, such as deciding you need an Arduino running on 5V.

If this is to be mounted on a pool cue, light weight and absence of wires are important requirements. This should direct your thinking toward low power wireless designs.

You can get a coin-sized PCB with a Bluetooth radio and 9-axis IMU, and mount it where the rubber bumper goes at the cue butt end. Data would be streamed to a phone, tablet, or laptop. I think you'll find accelerometers are very sensitive, and will pick up the "feathering", with far fewer glitches than your potentiometer idea. But you may want to define a "home" position of the cue as the stroke begins. You may be able to sense the light tap that occurs when the player sets the cue on his hand bridge. You'll also get a strong deceleration marker when the cue strikes the ball.

This isn't a shopping site, but as a proof of availability of a module that could work, see [this site](https://mbientlab.com/). You can also find PCBs with BLE+IMU on Amazon for less money, but with less firmware/software support.

Good luck on your interesting project!